# "Wrong number of arguments to #<procedure #f (music)>" when trying to execute a snippet from Lilypond Documentation

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I'm trying to use the code from a snippet found on [the official documentation on "Displaying pitches"](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/displaying-pitches#automatic-accidentals) (scroll down to "Known issues and warnings"):

```
\version "2.18.2"

forget = #(define-music-function (music) (ly:music?) #{
  \accidentalStyle forget
  #music
  \accidentalStyle modern
#})
{
  \accidentalStyle modern
  \time 2/4
  \repeat volta 2 {
    c'2
  }
  \alternative {
     \repeat volta 1 { cis' }
     \repeat volta 2 { \forget c' }
  }
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following error:

```
Changing working directory to: `/tmp'
Processing `/tmp/11678868158475380898.ly'
Parsing.../usr/share/lilypond/2.18.2/scm/ly-syntax-constructors.scm:56:23: In expression (apply (ly:music-function-extract fun) parser ...):
/usr/share/lilypond/2.18.2/scm/ly-syntax-constructors.scm:56:23: Wrong number of arguments to #<procedure #f (music)>
```

I get a similar error when trying other substitution functions, e.g. the ones provided [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/substitution-function-examples). I'm not familiar with Scheme so I can't really debug/analyze what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using Lilypond 2.18.2 on a Raspberry Pi, if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using examples from the manual for version 2.23 for LilyPond version 2.18, you may expect some things not to work.

However you arrived at that link, try replacing the `v2.23` string in its URL with `v2.18` and take your example code from there.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't expect such major structural changes (given how mature Lilypond is already). Indeed, I had to replace `(music)` with `(parser location music)` and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth pointing out that the code in the LilyPond manual produces the printed results *directly* in the process of creating the documentation HTML and PDF files.  That means that there is no code with printed results whatsoever that would "accidently" fail to compile absolutely as-is with the version corresponding to the manual.  What may happen is that the printed results differs from what you'd expect from the text description: in this case, this may be a documentation bug.  But it cannot happen that it fails to compile at all or produces a different visual result, as long as you are using the correct version.

You have *also* altered contents of `\alternative`, replacing it by something syntactically valid for 2.18 but contextually nonsensical, producing an absurd printed result.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the warning. That's what happens if you a few try things before submitting your code to Stack Exchange... I thought Lilypond might not recognize the main block as a music expression since it lacks a `\relative` command. (I knew about absolute notation, but thought you'd need to declare that specifically as well.)